# Custom launcher list all widgets

Tags: android, android-launcher

I am developing a launcher, based on the open source google launcher code. When opening the available widgets activity, I see that they are not all listed there (Now launcher definitely shows more - no Maps widgets listed). Is there a special permission or extra to be added in order to have them all listed? google doesn't seem to know much

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of filtering the launchable activities, and the open source launcher takes a very naive view of that.  Even Maps has multiple launchable activities (e.g. "Driving Mode") but you have to do a more nuanced look through the system than what the base launcher does.